# Linq Query: Group By

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by, distinct

I have 2 tables with the following fields:

> **Person**
>
> ID, LastName, FirstName
>
> **Assignment**
>
> PersonID, AssignmentDate, OtherField

Let's say the table data looks like this:

> **Person**
>
> - 1, Smith, John
> - 2, Allen, James
> - 3, Stone, Emma
>
> **Assignment**
>
> - 1, 12/1/2016, Blue
> - 1, 1/1/2017, Green
> - 1, 1/1/2018, Red
> - 2, 5/5/2015, Yellow

I'm building a report, and the logic states that...

- if the AssignmentDate's YEAR ends in an EVEN number, report the even number (if year is 2014, report 2014).
- If the AssignmentDate's year ends in an ODD number, report the year minus 1 (i.e., year is 2015, report 2014).

In addition, group by PersonID followed by that "even" AssignedYear. Include all persons and all assignments. (I wasn't sure if I should be using Group By or Distinct. Confused on this part.)

I need it to output these results based off the example table:

> - 1, 2016
> - 1, 2018
> - 2, 2014
> - 3, *null* (since personID = 3 exists, but there are no assignments, we still want to incorporate this person)

How would you do that? I've gotten this far, but got stuck. :(

```
var t = from p in tblPersons
        join a in tblAssignments
             on p.ID equals a.PersonID into fml
        from x in fml
        select new AssignmentFilters
              {
                  PersonID = x.PersonID,
                  Person= x.tblPersons.LastName + ", " + x.tblPersons.FirstName +
                       (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.tblPersons.PreferredName) ? "" : " (" + x.tblPersons.PreferredName + ")") +
                       (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.tblPersons.MiddleName) ? "" : " " + x.tblPersons.MiddleName) +
                       (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.tblPersons.Suffix) ? "" : " " + x.tblPersons.Suffix),
                  AuditStartYear = x.DateAssigned == null ? 0 : (x.DateAssigned.Year % 2 == 0 ? x.DateAssigned.Year : x.DateAssigned.Year - 1)
               };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Been working on this for the past few hours and am just frustrated/stumped, lol. Thank you!

Comment: What does your current code do now (i.e. which bits are working, which aren't)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq shows you how to do a left outer join (to get null).

Comment: @mjwills No errors with the above. The query brings back everything though. It's like an outer join. It yields at least 4 records (2 of 1, 2016; 1 of 1, 2018; 1 of 2, 2014). It might yield a 5th (for 3, null), but I haven't tested that hehe. It's when I attempt to start grouping things up that everything goes bonkers. ETA: If I throw in a group by, I can do it if it's an anonymous type object. But I need it to be a specific class that I've created, and so then it fails there. Or if I attempt to add in the statement expression into the select clause to... idk, it's just a mess when I try lol.

Comment: @mjwills I'm not having issues with the join. I'm having issues attempting to group by when there's a field that is a statement expression and when I need to specify the class type. Not sure if I can cast this list to a specified list type.

Comment: See msdn left outer join : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0):

isolate the audits per person based on the specific rules you mention

```
var audits = from assignment in tblAssignments
             select new
             {
                 PersonId = assignment.PersonID,
                 Year = assignment.DateAssigned == null
                     ? 0
                     : assignment.DateAssigned.Year % 2 == 0
                         ? assignment.DateAssigned.Year
                         : assignment.DateAssigned.Year - 1
             };
```

iterate over the persons and left outer join on the distinct of audits

```
var results = from person in tblPersons
            from audit in
            (
                from a in audits.Distinct()
                where a.PersonId == person.ID
                select a
            ).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
              Person = person,
              Audit = audit,
            };
```

this should give you something like this and then you can project the results even further in whatever shape you need

[image]